# Jquery UI Drag and Drop not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have Jquery drag and drop working in firefox, but it does not work in IE9.

I turned on display script errors on IE9 but its not displaying any errors..

The demo site is http://www.aussiehaulage.com.au/default.aspx

I have the latest versions of Jquery and UI

Comment: when you say you have the latest version of jQuery, is that v1.8? It was only released yesterday, so you may not have got it yet, but the release notes say they've fixed a lot of IE bugs.

Comment: Read the ticket: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5370

Comment: thanks :) ill try that. you should have put it as an answer as i would have marked it correct :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue will get fixed with this fix. Use this fix in your code and enjoy.

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-sortable-and-draggable-do-not-work-in-ie9
This will be in jQuery UI 1.8.6.

If you can't upgrade to 1.8.6 (yet), this hotfix will allow older versions of jQuery UI drag-and-drop to work with IE9:

```
<script>
// HOTFIX: We can't upgrade to jQuery UI 1.8.6 (yet)
// This hotfix makes older versions of jQuery UI drag-and-drop work in IE9

(function($){
    var a=$.ui.mouse.prototype._mouseMove;
    $.ui.mouse.prototype._mouseMove=function(b){
        if($.browser.msie&&document.documentMode>=9){
            b.button=1
        };
        a.apply(this,[b]);
    }
}(jQuery));
</script>
```