# drag and drop not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

Im working on Drag and Drop web application using jQuery UI version 1.12.0. Drag and drop is working in Chrome but not working in IE9 and I have upgraded the IE version 9.0 to IE11.

But again the same issue, I have google it and found the following discussion on the stakoverflow.
[Jquery UI Drag and Drop not working in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914249/jquery-ui-drag-and-drop-not-working-in-ie9)

I have tried the Hotfix code discussed in the above link. But still I'm facing the same issue.